# android - dismiss spinner when user touches somewhere else

Tags: android, android-spinner, ontouchlistener, dismiss

I have an app where the user presses a button and a custom spinner is popped so that the user can choose between nine colors. I want the spinner to be dismissed, when the user touches the background (every place on the sreen except from the spinner). Is this possible?

I tried to add an onTouchListener on the image that covers the background and call

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

but it does not work.

My spinner is custom Spinner, set in an xml file and popped with:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.colorchooser);
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you should be able to add

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

to accomplish what you want.

But the dismiss() method should also be working, I would guess that the place your are calling dialog.dismiss() is not reachable at the current moment.

Comment: dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!